# SQL Trouble with second part of WHERE NOT EXIST query

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m trying to create a website that creates a recommendation to a student on what classes they should take for the next semester based on what classes have been completed in the student’s transcript and what is left to take in their degree’s curriculum.

My first idea was to query for all the Courses_Codes in the curriculum that are not in the student’s transcript. I have done that with the query below.

```
SELECT Course_Code, Course_Sequence, Prereq_ID
FROM Curriculum 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Transcript 
WHERE curriculum.course_code = transcript.course_code
AND transcript.CWID = "C38475920");
```

However, I need to narrow down the query even more so that I’m not recommending the student a course that has a course prerequisite that the student does not meet. The Prereq_ID in the curriculum table holds the prerequisite for each course. I’m totally stuck on how to add additional code to the query above and get a result that returns all the curriculum.Course_Code that are not in a specific student’s transcript **(CWID is the student’s ID. Each class the student has taken has a corresponding CWID)** and also make sure the prerequisite is met by maybe adding something like this?
`transcript.Course_Code = curriculum.Prereq_ID`

If that doesn’t make sense I know this isn’t proper SQL but:

```
SELECT curriculum.Course_Code
FROM curriculum 
WHERE curriculum.Course_Code  IS NOT IN transcript 
AND transcript.Course_Code = curriculum.Prereq_ID
AND transcript.CWID = "C38475920”;
```

Here's the curriculum and transcript table:

```
protected $table ="curriculum";
    protected $fillable = [
      'Program_ID', //Primary Key //int
      'Curriculum_ID', //varchar
      'Maj_Code',//varchar
      'Course_Code',//varchar
      'Course_Seq', //int
      'Prereq_ID',//varchar
      'Course_Desc',//varchar
    ];
    protected $table ="transcript";
    protected $fillable = [
      'Transcript_ID', //primary key 
      'CWID', //foreign key //varchar
      'Maj_Code', //varchar
      'Curriculum_ID', //varchar
      'Course_Comp',//varchar
      'Term_Completed',//varchar
      'Course_Grade',//varchar
      'Course_Code',//varchar
    ];
```

Hopefully that makes the result I’m trying to get clear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it would help if you [edit] your question and post schema details, i.e. table names, column names, column data types, primary keys and foreign keys. While these details may be well known to you, that doesn't mean they are to people reading your question.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, first get all the courses from the curriculum which is not in transcript and then do an inner join ( to get intersection ) with transcript again based on prereq_id matching course_code. Maybe the keyword distinct is not required.

`select distinct course_code from ( select c.* from curriculum as c where c.course_code not in ( select t.course_code from transcript as t where t.CWID = 'C38475920') ) as c2 inner join transcript t2 on t2.course_code = c2.Prereq_ID;`

Comment: Thanks for the response! It gave an error though #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. It looks like the code you gave is right though

Comment: You also need to add `where t.cwid`  condition.

Comment: @DelB95 have added alias , please check again.

Comment: I had to change course_code to `c2.course_code` for it to run. Sadly it is returning courses that the has a prerequisite that the student has not met and it will return courses that the student has already taken. I appreciate the help though

Comment: @DelB95 too bad, I thought that the query was correct. (I still think it is) You can downvote it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the following query. Your question is confusing because you state "CWID is the student's ID," but immediately afterward you contradict yourself by saying "Each class the student has taken has a corresponding CWID." So CWID does not appear to be a unique ID for a student, perhaps it is a unique ID for a pairing of student and course taken. In any case, there is probably a `student` table that is missing from what you have posted above, but I think you can solve your problem by having the student's transcript ID. Presumably, a student can only have one transcript ID.

I am basing my answer below on the following assumptions:

1. A student can only have one `transcript_id`
2. The `prereq_id` represents the `course_id` that is the prerequisite for the course on each row of the `curriculum` table
3. The `course_id` is unique, no two different courses can share the same value (across different `program_id` values, for example)

I am confused by the significance of `program_id` because you say that that column is a primary key, yet `course_id` is not, on the `curriculum` table. That doesn't make sense. Presumably a "program" would be something like biology, education, accounting, etc. and such programs would have 2+ courses. How could the `program_id` be a primary key on a table where there is a `course_code` column, given that there must be 2+ courses in a program...?

```
select    c.course_code
          c.course_sequence
          c.prereq_id
from      curriculum      c
     join transcript      t
       on c.prereq_id = t.course_code
left join transcript      x 
       on c.course_code = x.course_code
      and t.transcript_id = x.transcript_id
where     t.transcript_id = 'xxxxx'
      and x.course_code is null;
```